# Is there a way to overwrite an array when I push a new value to it?

Tags: javascript

Maybe I am doing this wrong but I'm trying to update my arrays so that they just have the most current thing submitted in them. Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to think of anything and push just adds more to the array each time.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


var divisTwo = [];
var divisThree = [];

function getNumbers(nums){
    // iterates through these to determine if fiz, buzz or fizzbuzz.
    if(nums % 105 === 0){
        return 'Fizz Buzz Pop'
    } else if (nums % 35 === 0){
        return 'Buzz Pop'
    } else if (nums % 21 === 0){
        return 'Fizz Pop'
    }  else if (nums % 15 === 0){
        return 'Fizz Buzz'
    } else if (nums % 7 === 0){
        return 'Pop'
    } else if(nums % 5 === 0 ){
        return 'Buzz'
    } else if(nums % 3 === 0){
        return  divisThree || 'Fizz'
    } else if (nums % 2 === 0){
        return divisTwo
    } else {
        return nums
    }
};
$('#click').click(function(){
    // Gets value from input box.
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("fizz-input").value;
    // appends text to an h2 in the html
    $("#fizz-buzz-output").text(getNumbers(inputValue));
});
$('#change-names').click(function test(name){
    var multiTwo = document.getElementById("multiples-of-two").value;
    var multiThree = document.getElementById("multiples-of-three").value;


    divisTwo.push(multiTwo);
    divisThree.push(multiThree);
    console.log(divisTwo);
    console.log(divisThree);
});
});
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you looking to build on your array on every click, or only store the most recent values (in which case an array wouldn't seem to make much sense)?

Comment: Where is _push_ in your code?

Comment: If you want only single item to be stored in array, do you really need an array? Why not use simple variables? How are you submitting these values?

Comment: @VivekAthalye so I need access to them in my other function that is why I was pushing

Comment: @VivekAthalye push would just keep adding to the array, I need this to replace what is in the array every time submit is clicked so I can use it in another function.

Comment: How many items do you want to store in each array? One, or more?

Comment: @aendeerei I added the whole code if this helps.

Comment: @VivekAthalye I added the full code if that helps you

Comment: What do you expect to receive when you say `return divisTwo`? An array, a string, an integer? same question for `return divisThree...`.

Comment: @aendeerei both divisTwo and divisThree will be strings

Comment: Then the answer is as @VivekAthalye proposed: use two simple variables instead of the arrays.

Comment: @aendeerei so how would I write that?

Comment: what do mean by overwrite an array to you want to replace some of the value in array

Comment: It would be written as in @VivekAthalye's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple variables instead of arrays.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


var divisTwo;
var divisThree;

function getNumbers(nums){
    // iterates through these to determine if fiz, buzz or fizzbuzz.
    if(nums % 105 === 0){
        return 'Fizz Buzz Pop'
    } else if (nums % 35 === 0){
        return 'Buzz Pop'
    } else if (nums % 21 === 0){
        return 'Fizz Pop'
    }  else if (nums % 15 === 0){
        return 'Fizz Buzz'
    } else if (nums % 7 === 0){
        return 'Pop'
    } else if(nums % 5 === 0 ){
        return 'Buzz'
    } else if(nums % 3 === 0){
        return  divisThree || 'Fizz'
    } else if (nums % 2 === 0){
        return divisTwo
    } else {
        return nums
    }
};
$('#click').click(function(){
    // Gets value from input box.
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("fizz-input").value;
    // appends text to an h2 in the html
    $("#fizz-buzz-output").text(getNumbers(inputValue));
});
$('#change-names').click(function test(name){
    divisTwo = document.getElementById("multiples-of-two").value;
    divisThree = document.getElementById("multiples-of-three").value;

    console.log(divisTwo);
    console.log(divisThree);
});
});
```

Comment: @aendeerei yes, me too. I wanted to avoid many changes as it was difficult to submit the answer from mobile :D

Answer (score 0):

You must equate your variable of array to empty inside the function, so that every fire of the click event, it is empty. Also don't use pop, because it only removes last element.

```
var divisTwo = [];
var divisThree = [];

$('#change-names').click(function(){

divisTwo = [];
divisThree = [];

var multiTwo = document.getElementById("multiples-of-two").value;
    var multiThree = document.getElementById("multiples-of-three").value;

    divisTwo.push(multiTwo);
    divisThree.push(multiThree);
    console.log(divisTwo);
    console.log(divisThree);
});
```

Comment: The reason the vars are where they are is because I need access to them in another function

Comment: I edited my answer. You can access your variable outside the function.

Comment: Based on your question, you're trying to set new values in your array upon click. Is that correct? If so, then this would work

Comment: @Bkes pop only removes last element in array